# Passing IPPReferenceType for parentref but the still sub customer data is not adding up in Quickbook API online

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I almost went through all the sources to find the fix for this.

I need to add a sub customer to a customer in quickbooks thru php.

I have already marked true to job in the object and also passing the IPPReferenceType object for ParentRef yet the data is not reflecting.

This is the object which I am passing :

```
IPPCustomer Object (
[Taxable] => 
[BillAddr] => 
[ShipAddr] => 
[OtherAddr] => 
[ContactName] => 
[AltContactName] => 
[Notes] => 
[Job] => 1
[BillWithParent] => 
[RootCustomerRef] => 
[ParentRef] => IPPReferenceType Object
    (
        [name] => 
        [type] => 
        [value] => 95
    )

[Level] => 
[CustomerTypeRef] => 
[SalesTermRef] => 
[SalesRepRef] => 
[TaxGroupCodeRef] => 
[TaxRateRef] => 
[PaymentMethodRef] => 
[CCDetail] => 
[PriceLevelRef] => 
[Balance] => 
[OpenBalanceDate] => 
[BalanceWithJobs] => 
[CreditLimit] => 
[AcctNum] => 
[CurrencyRef] => 
[OverDueBalance] => 
[TotalRevenue] => 
[TotalExpense] => 
[PreferredDeliveryMethod] => 
[ResaleNum] => 
[JobInfo] => 
[CustomerEx] => 
[IntuitId] => 
[Organization] => 
[Title] => 
[GivenName] => Pratibha
[MiddleName] => 
[FamilyName] => Mishra
[Suffix] => 
[FullyQualifiedName] => 
[CompanyName] => 
[DisplayName] => Pratibha Mishra
[PrintOnCheckName] => 
[UserId] => 
[Active] => 1
[PrimaryPhone] => IPPTelephoneNumber Object
    (
        [Id] => 
        [DeviceType] => 
        [CountryCode] => 
        [AreaCode] => 
        [ExchangeCode] => 
        [Extension] => 
        [FreeFormNumber] => (418) 124-6538
        [Default] => 
        [Tag] => 
    )

[AlternatePhone] => IPPTelephoneNumber Object
    (
        [Id] => 
        [DeviceType] => 
        [CountryCode] => 
        [AreaCode] => 
        [ExchangeCode] => 
        [Extension] => 
        [FreeFormNumber] => (418) 478-6538
        [Default] => 
        [Tag] => 
    )

[Mobile] => 
[Fax] => 
[PrimaryEmailAddr] => IPPEmailAddress Object
    (
        [Id] => 
        [Address] => ross@geller.lcl
        [Default] => 
        [Tag] => 
    )

[WebAddr] => 
[OtherContactInfo] => 
[DefaultTaxCodeRef] => 
[Id] => 
[SyncToken] => 
[MetaData] => 
[CustomField] => 
[AttachableRef] => 
[domain] => 
[status] => 
[sparse] => 
)
```

As you can see I have a customer with the value 95 and I am passing the same to ParentRef for this object which is a sub customer.

I am using php to integrate the data into quickbooks and I am using V3QBO package.

Please let me know you suggestions and advice.
Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the above issue by setting the true value as string instead of a boolean, like this:

[Job] => 'true';

same thing will happen with BillWithParent and the workarround as well.

Reference link

https://intuitdeveloper.lc.intuit.com/questions/1039309-can-t-set-a-customer-as-job-or-sub-customer-using-php-and-sdk-v3

Comment: Thanks for the answer, further I have fetched the parent data from quickbook online using their SQL and passed that data to parentRef => value and name.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to create a JOB/Sub customer in QBO company file and then read via code. Compare it with what you are sending to see if you are missing something.
Setting JOB(not jobinfo) and ParentRef should be it.